# Hamburger menu + shrinking header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was advised to repost my question, as I did not phrase it correctly previously.

I have a hamburger menu (see here: http://codepen.io/Dingerzat/pen/zKXARr ), that I want to work with a shrinking header (see here: http://codepen.io/Nickies/pen/ZYwJZM ). Putting the two codes directly together hasn't worked. The shrinking header and resizing logo ceases to function on scrolling.

I am not sure what is causing this. Any advice would be brilliant.

Posting the code my combined version below:

HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <h1 id="logo">
            LOGO
        </h1>
        <div class="hamburger-menu">
          <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="text">MENU</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</header><!-- /header -->

 <nav>
        <ul role="navigation" class="overlay hidden">
            <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">RESUME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
 </nav>

<div class="contacts">
      <address>someperson@somewhere.com</address>
</div>

<div class="bigtext">THIS IS PLACEHOLDER</div>
```

CSS

```
@import "compass/css3";

$bar-width: 50px;
$bar-height: 4px;
$bar-spacing: 15px;

body {
    background: #000000;
  font-family: Teko;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.hamburger-menu {
    position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 45px;
  left: 45px;
  margin: auto;
  width: $bar-width;
    height: $bar-height + $bar-spacing*2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.text {
    margin-left: 60px;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transition: all 350ms ease-in-out;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.show .text {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX( -10px );
}


.bar,
.bar:after,
.bar:before {
  width: $bar-width;
    height: $bar-height;
}

.bar {
    position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
    transform: translateY($bar-spacing);
    background: rgba(188, 49, 254, 1);
    transition: all 0ms 300ms;

  .show & {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); 
  }
}

.bar:before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    bottom: $bar-spacing;
    background: rgba(188, 49, 254, 1);
    transition: bottom 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.bar:after {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: $bar-spacing;
    background: rgba(188, 49, 254, 1);
    transition: top 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}

.show .bar:after {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    transition: top 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);;
}

.show .bar:before {
    bottom: 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    transition: bottom 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1), transform 300ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1em;
  border-color: black;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #bc31fe;
}
nav ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Teko;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;

  &.hidden {
    display: none;
  }

    a {
    @include transition-duration(0.5s);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    }
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
}

.overlay .contacts {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 37px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: .01em;
    z-index: 2;
}
.contacts {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #10131a;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
}

.bigtext {
  font-size: 50em;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: #0683c9;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: height 0.3s;
    -o-transition: height 0.3s;
    transition: height 0.3s;
}
header h1#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    float: center;
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
header nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
header nav a {
    line-height: 150px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #9fdbfc;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 18px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
header nav a:hover {
    color: white;
}
header.smaller {
    height: 75px;
}
header.smaller h1#logo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
header.smaller nav a {
    line-height: 75px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 660px) {
    header h1#logo {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 100px;
        line-height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    header nav {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    header nav a {
        line-height: 50px;
        margin: 0 10px;
    }
    header.smaller {
        height: 75px;
    }
    header.smaller h1#logo {
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    header.smaller nav {
        height: 35px;
    }
    header.smaller nav a {
        line-height: 35px;
    }
}
```

JS

```
( function () {

    var $navUL = $( 'nav ul' );

    $( '.hamburger-menu' ).on( 'click', function () {

        $( this ).toggleClass( 'show' );
        $navUL.toggleClass( 'hidden' );

    } );

} )();

function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 300,
            header = document.querySelector("header");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(header,"smaller");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                classie.remove(header,"smaller");
            }
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
```

Comment: If you provide a link to your codepen of your attempted solution as well, it tends to make it easier for people to diagnose the issues...

Comment: http://codepen.io/Dingerzat/pen/XjQQWZ here you go. I would have posted it in the original post, but I am not allowed to post more than two links atm.